# Why is only one of my AC blowers producing cold air?

Tags: electrical, air-conditioning

When I turned on my Kolin aircon, one blower is blowing out cold air and the other is blowing warm air.

When I shut the one that is blowing cold air (leaving the one that is blowing warm air), the fan stopped spinning.

I opened up the compressor compartment, I have 2 compressor capacitors (30 UF 450VAC) and a fan capacitor 3.5UF 450VAC).

Now all (on the surface) seemed good.

I wanted to change all of them to new ones. BUT with only 440VAC. IS this correct or allowed?

Will I end up under voltage and spoil the aircon?

Edit: ThreePhaseEel: I am from the Philippines. Xeeka: The capacitor voltage is 450

Mr Ed Beal: Could you kindly explain on the reversing valve which you have mentioned is in the wrong place. And where can I find this valve. It's a Multi Split Airocn with 2 blower: KOLIN KSG-20B2 single phase.

Comment: Throwing capacitors randomly at a problem rarely solves it.

Comment: A split system with one blowing warm and 1 cold has nothing to do with capacitors. Verify the temperature setting on the unit blowing warm air. 
To me it sounds like a reversing valve is in the wrong position. Don’t start shotgunning parts. Verify there are no trouble codes on the 2nd unit also we need the make and model of the compressor and the inside units.

Comment: My aircon model and brand is KOLIN KSG-20B2. What is a reversing valve, where can I find it and how to know that it is in a reverse position?

Comment: My KOLIN aircon has 2 cirlinder shape capacitors (30 UF) for 2 blowers and a small rectangle black capacitor (3.5UF) for Fan.They are all 450VAC.

Comment: My KOLIN aircon has 2 cirlinder shape capacitors (30 UF) for 2 blowers and a small rectangle black capacitor (3.5UF) for Fan.They are all 450VAC. I have just change them to new ones. That is, the 2 capacitors for compressor (30UF) BUT at 440VAC and the Fan capacitor (3.5UF) BUY at 440 VAC. Upon turning on, I am faced with the same problem. That is, upon shutting off the blower blowing cold air with fan running, leaving the other blower on BUT the Fan stopped immediately.

Comment: NOW, my KOLIN aricon is an inverter type. When the derised room temperature was reached (I supposed the blower that blew cold air), the Compressor and the Fan stopped. BUT there is a struggling humming sound for a abt 2 mins before it stopped all together and the unit remain silent. Normally, when the inverter kicks in, the Compressor and the fan stopped for a while before restart again. During this time the unit is quiet. What do you thing is the problem/s? Please advice. Thanks

Comment: An aircon contractor told me that it could be due to the Freon problem. Need servicng and top up? BUT our unit is very clean and there is no sign of leaking. Is his opinion correct?

Comment: BY the way, we are staying in the Philippines.

Comment: Also, there are no blockage to the drainage pipes. NO frost build up during opeation. The only thing is that when the unit is on, when I touched one of the copper pipe, it is cold (normally) while the other that feeds into the blower remains warm. Please advice. Thanks a lot!